# "free(): invalid pointer" error occurs when returning an eigen matrix

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, matrix, eigen

I am doing some iterative calculation on tensor. I have to map the tensor to a matrix in the calculation. The library I use for matrix operation is "Eigen".

Description of the class Tensor:

1. the * operator is overloaded to perform tensor multiplication. (Common indices are summed over)

Description of the class SVD:

1. It is used to perform singular value decomposition (SVD).
2. The decomposition is done by Eigen::JacobiSVD.
3. It serves to output ltensor and rtensor (both rank 3) in the program.
4. Example: if the input matrix is D^2xD^2, the ltensor is DxDxD^2, the rtensor is D^2xDxD.
5. Multiplication of ltensor and rtensor will give the original tensor.

Description of the program:

1. The initial tensor is rank 4 with the dimension of each index to be 2 (2x2x2x2). It is then mapped to a 4x4 matrix by the function "transform_to_matrix()".
2. After some calculations, the dimension of each index of tensor T is enlarged to 4 (4x4x4x4).
3. In the next iteration, I expect the new tensor is mapped to a 16x16 matrix.

Error:
The error "free(): invalid pointer" occurs at the line labelled with (*) in the second iteration.

```
void SOLVE::solve(){
  Tensor S=this->tensor_; // initial tensor with index {"u","d","l","r"}
  std::vector<std::string> row1{"u","l"};
  std::vector<std::string> col1{"d","r"};
  std::vector<std::string> row2{"u","r"};
  std::vector<std::string> col2{"d","l"};
  Tensor S1;
  Tensor S2;
  Tensor S3;
  Tensor S4;
  SVD svd;
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    std::cout << i<< "check" << std::endl;
    Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> matrix1=
    transform_to_matrix(S,row1,col1); // (*) map to matrix by the sets of 
                                      // indices
    std::cout << i<< "check" << std::endl;
    svd.set_matrix(matrix1); // input matrix to do SVD
    svd.solve(); // solve the SVD
    S1=svd.get_ltensor("u","l","e"); // "u", "l", "e" are for index 
                                     // labeling
    S3=svd.get_rtensor("f","r","d"); // "f", "r", "d" are for index
                                     // labeling
    Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic>matrix2=
    transform_to_matrix(S,row2,col2); // map to matrix by another sets of 
                                      // indices
    svd.set_matrix(matrix2); // update to new matrix
    svd.solve(); // solve the SVD problem again
    S4=svd.get_ltensor("u","r","g"); 
    S2=svd.get_rtensor("h","d","l"); 
    S1.set_index("u","a"); // rename the index "u" to "a"
    S1.set_index("l","n");
    S1.set_index("e","r");
    S2.set_index("l","b");
    S2.set_index("d","a");
    S2.set_index("h","u");
    S3.set_index("r","b");
    S3.set_index("d","m");
    S3.set_index("f","l");
    S4.set_index("u","m");
    S4.set_index("r","n");
    S4.set_index("g","d");
    // Indice of
    // S1: {"a","n","r"}
    // S2: {"b","a","u"}
    // S3: {"b","m","l"}
    // S4: {"m","n","d"}
    S=S1*S2*S3*S4; // indices of S: {"u","d","l","r"}
  }      
}

Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic>       
transform_to_matrix
(const Tensor &S,
std::vector<std::string> row,
std::vector<std::string> col)
{
  // This function will map a DxDxDxD tensor to a D^2xD^2 matrix,
  // according to the row indices and col indices required.
  // Example:
  // row={"u","d"}, col={"l","r"}
  // The indices "u" and "d" are grouped into the row
  // The indices "l" and "r" are grouped into the col
  Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> matrix;
  ... // some mapping procedures.
  std::cout << matrix << std::endl;
  return matrix;
}
```

Program output:

```
0check
... (a 4*4 matrix is printed here)
0check
1check
... (a 16*16 matrix is printed here)
Error message is printed here: "free(): invalid pointer:"
```

The 16x16 matrix is printed out, so everything is fine until the end in the function transform_to_matrix(). So the problem is the "matrix" in the second iteration cannot accept the return from transform_to_matrix().
Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

**Update:**

The error is sometimes "free(): invalid next size (fast):" and sometimes "free(): invalid pointer".

Use gdb to debug

Output:

```
0check
... (a 4*4 matrix is printed here)
0check
1check
... (a 16*16 matrix is printed here)
Error message is printed here: "free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000006c5570" 
...
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff71a1428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at 
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

Type bt:

```
#0  0x00007ffff71a1428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007ffff71a302a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff71e37ea in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, 
fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff72fce98 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at 
../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff71ec37a in malloc_printerr (ar_ptr=<optimized out>, 
ptr=<optimized out>, str=0x7ffff72fcf10 "free(): invalid next size 
(fast)", action=3) at malloc.c:5006
#4  _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at 
malloc.c:3867
#5  0x00007ffff71f053c in __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at 
malloc.c:2968
#6  0x0000000000404cbe in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate 
(this=0x7fffffffcc90, __p=0x6c5570) at 
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:110
#7  0x00000000004048b0 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> 
>::deallocate (__a=..., __p=0x6c5570, __n=2) at 
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/alloc_traits.h:517
#8  0x0000000000404268 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> 
>::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fffffffcc90, __p=0x6c5570, __n=2) at 
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:178
#9  0x0000000000403813 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> 
>::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffffcc90, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at 
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:160
#10 0x0000000000407fdd in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> 
>::~vector (this=0x7fffffffcc90, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at 
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:425
#11 0x0000000000467795 in transform_to_matrix (t=..., row=std::vector 
of length 2, capacity 2 = {...}, 
col=std::vector of length 2, capacity 2 = {...}) at helper.cpp:189
#12 0x000000000040bcc2 in SOLVE::solve (this=0x7fffffffe1e0) at 
solve.cpp:22
#13 0x0000000000402279 in main () at main.cpp:43
```

#13:

```
t.solve(); // call solve(); main.cpp:43
```

#12:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> matrix1=transform_to_matrix(S,row1,col1); // give error in the second iteration; solve.cpp:22
```

#11:

```
std::vector<int> col_arr(col_size,0); // col_size=2 ; helper.cpp:189
```

Comment: I would look at the Tensor class copy constructor, copy assignment, and destructor.  I suspect there is an error in either one of them, failing to properly implement the rule of 3.

Comment: Does it also happen when you pass `Tensor const &T` instead of `Tensor T`?

Comment: @DaveS I do not define copy constructor and destructor.

Comment: @HenriMenke I tried, but the same error appears.

Comment: Please use a debugger to properly spot the location of the issue! Combining it with an address/memory sanitizer might also help. The problem could likely be in Tensor or SVD and not in the code you show.

Comment: @ggael I have added the debugging message. It seems like the error is really from the transform_to_matrix(), but I don't understand why does it track to the line "std::vector<int> col_arr(col_size,0);", I can't see any problem with it. In fact, just above it, I have declared 3 similar vector<int>, and 5 more vector<int> below it.

Comment: You probably have memory errors occurring before. Use a memory debugger to find them (e.g., valgrind or clang's memory sanitizer)